# php code to search for word variations using the asterisk (*)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make search box with ability to search for word variations using the asterisk (*).

An asterisk (*) replaces one letter, can be used more than once in a word.

**For example**, searching on the term wom*n will locate records containing both woman and women and so on...

**Any tips to achieve this in PHP ?**

Comment: Replace `*`, with `_` in your like clause.

Comment: do you mean 

SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE col LIKE 'wom_n';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wil do this with a database.

```
// The var we will use: $_POST['var']

$query = "SELECT  FROM yourTable WHERE name LIKE ".translateVar($_POST['var']);

function translateVar($n){
    return str_replace("*", "_", $n);
}
```